# Can i pass component state to HoC?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, high-order-component

Is there any way to send data from the component's state to HoC?

My component

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import withHandleError from './withHandleError';

class SendScreen extends Component {

  contructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      error: true
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <div> Test </div>
    )
  }
};


export default withHandleError(SendScreen)
```

My HoC component:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ErrorScreen } from '../../ErrorScreen';
import { View } from 'react-native';

export default Cmp => {
  return class extends Component {
    render() {
      const { ...rest } = this.props;
      console.log(this.state.error)  //// Cannot read property 'error' of null
      if (error) {
        return <ErrorScreen />
      }

      return <Cmp { ...rest } />
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any way to do this?

Is the only option is to provide props that must come to the SendScreen component from outside??

Comment: AFAIK the only way to do that would be to handle state in the HOC and pass them as props to the component below. Good article on it here https://daveceddia.com/extract-state-with-higher-order-components/

Answer (score 0):

A parent isn't aware of child's state. While it can get an instance of a child with a ref and access `state`, it can't watch on state updates, the necessity to do this indicates design problem.

This is the case for [lifting up the state](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). A parent needs to be notified that there was an error:

```
export default Cmp => {
  return class extends Component {
    this.state = {
      error: false
    }

    onError() = () => this.setState({ error: true });

    render() {
      if (error) {
        return <ErrorScreen />
      }

      return <Cmp onError={this.onError} { ...this.props } />
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export default withHandleError(data)(SendScreen)
```

In **data** you can send the value you want to pass to HOC, and can access as prop.

Answer (score 0):

I know I answer late, but my answer can help other people

It is very easy to do.

1. WrappedComponent

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import HocComponent from './HocComponent';

const propTypes = {
  passToHOC: PropTypes.func,
};

class WrappedComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: true,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const {passToHOC} = this.props;
    const {error} = this.state;
    passToHOC(error); // <---  pass the <<error>> to the HOC component
  }

  render() {
    return <div> Test </div>;
  }
}

WrappedComponent.propTypes = propTypes;
export default HocComponent(WrappedComponent);
```

2. HOC Component

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default WrappedComponent => {
  return class extends Component {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {
        error: false,
      };
    }
    doAnything = error => {
      console.log(error); //<-- <<error === true>> from child component
      this.setState({error});
    };
    render() {
      const {error} = this.state;
      if (error) {
        return <div> ***error*** passed successfully</div>;
      }

      return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} passToHOC={this.doAnything} />;
    }
  };
};
```

[React docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

Answer (score -1):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import withHandleError from './withHandleError';

class SendScreen extends Component {

  contructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      error: true
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <div state={...this.state}> Test </div>
    )
  }
};


export default withHandleError(SendScreen)
```

You can pass the state as a prop in your component.